# LowpassFilter Mathematica

Tags: signal-processing

I have this example signal:

```
w1 = 3; (* rad/s *)
w2 = 50; (* rad/s *)
w3 = 4;  (* rad/s *)
signal[t_] = Sin[w1*t] + Sin[w2*t] - Sin[w3*t]
```

[image]

I would filtrer this signal with ideal Low Pass filter (w3=50 rad/s) using command `LowpassFilter`such that the filtered signal is:

```
signalF[t_] = Sin[w1*t] - Sin[w3*t]
```

[image]

I tried so:

```
data = Table[signal[t], {t, 0, 5, 0.01}];
wc=50;
n=200; (*What does it mean specifically this parameter?*)
ListLinePlot[LowpassFilter[data, 50, 200, DirichletWindow]]
```

but I got the same starting signal.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Moo sorry, I edited post

Comment: How about `Show[Plot[signal[t], {t, 0, 5}], 
 ListLinePlot[LowpassFilter[data, 0.5/(2 Pi)], DataRange -> {0, 5}]]`? You need to take into account the sampling and `2 Pi` of the sine.

Comment: @corey979 Thx, more or less he is the filtered signal I expected, through your command:
https://s11.postimg.org/yy2lspl37/SNAG_0011.png

but why wc=0.5/(2*pi)? ... if my wc=50 rad/sec.
Maybe wc in the command is not a pulsation but frequency w/(2*pi)? If yes, why 0.5? Furthermore why without DirichletWindow?
Thx

Comment: From the docs, _Details and Options_ of `LowpassFilter`: "`LowpassFilter[data,Subscript[\[Omega], c]]` uses a filter kernel length and smoothing window suitable for the cutoff frequency `Subscript[\[Omega], c]` and the input data" - I guess `DirichletWindow` is default. What's more important, "By default, `SampleRate->1` is assumed for images as well as data".

Comment: @ corey979 I have read your comment too late, sorry.

Comment: @rewi No problem; you could, though, give a quantitative explanation of why choose 0.1 rather than 50 as a cutoff frequency - what is it truly related to. I'm too occupied with now to dig into the details.

Comment: @corey979 thx ;)

Comment: Just a side note: `LowpassFilter` seems to be improved (or even bug-fixed?) in v11 or earlier, in v9 I have to manually adjust the 3rd argument of it to obtain a reasonable result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sABt7.png

Comment: "`n=200; (*What does it mean specifically this parameter?*)`", so you found this code piece somewhere else?

Comment: @xzczd no. If I used a windows smoothing this paramater is required, so I tried a trial value n=200.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I think it's better to ask this in a clearer way in the question e.g. "what's the meaning of the 3rd argument of `LowpassFilter`?"

Comment: @xzczd Your are right! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
w1 = 3; w2 = 50; w3 = 4; 
signal = Sin[w1*t] + Sin[w2*t] - Sin[w3*t];
data = Table[signal, {t, 0, 5, 1/100}] // N;
```

**Edit**

To play with the cut frequency I have made this edit.

```
  Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[signal, {t, 0, 5}], 
  ListLinePlot[LowpassFilter[data, w], DataRange -> {0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Darker@Red]],
 {w, 0.5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

I prefer filter with well-known transfer function, e.g. Butterworth filter. One can adjust the passband and stopband frequencies and the attenuations. Here, I choose a loss of 30 dB at the frequency of w2 = 50.

```
filter = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", {w3, w2}, {0.1, 30}}, s];
out[t_] = OutputResponse[filter, signal, {t, 0, 6}];
ϕ = Arg[filter[N[I*w3]]]/w3; (*phase shift*)
Plot[{signal, out[t - ϕ]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: thx, I have a doubt, Why w = 0.5/(2*pi) if wc = 50 rad/s?

Comment: @plus91 The transfer function of the `LowpassFilter` is unknown (for us). One must minimize therefore the cutoff frequency as far as until the desired result is achieved (~ 0.1). That's why I brought the `Manipulate` example. In contrast to the Butterworth filter. Here one can exact define the stopband frequency (w2 = 50 Hz). Look at "Details and Options" in the documentation for the use of `LowpassFilter`.

Comment: something is very wrong to me. To filter a signal at a given wc so I always know the end result and verify that you corrected, varying wc LowpassFilter in command?

Comment: @plus91 `Lowpassfilter` is not the right tool to filter out a frequency. If you set the cutoff frequency to w2 = 2 Pi f = 50 Hz, then, this frequency is still undamped. You must lower the cutoff frequency as far as until this frequency disappears. You don't know how far it is now toned down in contrast to the Butterworth filter. It has a loss of 30 dB at w2 = 50 Hz and the frequencies w1 and w3 are undamped.

Comment: Now it is clearer, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will restrict my answer to a class of signals given in the example. The signal is a Sine series, and I am assuming that w1, w2 and w3 are integers. Therefore you can extract the coeffients of the series:

```
coeffs = Table[FourierSinCoefficient[signal[t], t, n], {n, 50}]
```

with $n$ an integer that depends on your highest frequency.

Build your low pass filter by selecting the coeffs within your low frequency range:

```
LowPassFilter[coeffs_, n_] := Take[coeffs, n]
```

and reconstruct your filtered signal:

```
lowcoeffs = LowPassFilter[coeffs, 4];
funcs = Table[Sin[n t], {n, Length[lowcoeffs]}];
smoothsignal[t_] := LowPassFilter[coeffs, 4].funcs;
```

The resulting plot:

```
Plot[{smoothsignal[t], signal[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: thx for you answer  ;)